# Работа с <select><select/> JS

Tags: javascript, html, websqldatabase

Есть выпадающий список:

```
 <select id = "idNotes"></select>
```

После загрузки страницы необходимо установить определенное число option - ов, соответствующие количеству записей в таблице WebSQl. Есть событие загрузки страницы, после него получаем количество записей из БД:

```
  db = openDatabase("Phones", "0.1", "A list of phones", 100);
  if(!db){ alert("Failed to connect to database."); }
  else{alert("Success to connect to database.");} 

  var countNotes = 0;

  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PHONES", [], function (tx, result) {
        countNotes =  result.rows.length;
    }, null);
 });
```

Как собрать это в одну функцию, загружающуюся после загрузки документа и устанавливающую option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makeOptions() {
    db = openDatabase('Phones', '0.1', 'A list of phones', 100);

    if(!db)
        return void alert('Failed to connect to database.');
    else  alert('Success to connect to database.');

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PHONES', [], function(tx, result) {
            var optinons = '';

            for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
                optinons += '<option>' + result.rows[i] + '</option>';

            document.getElementById('idNotes').innerHTML = optinons;
        }, null);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', makeOptions);
```